# Wrapper for TestComplete Function "FindChild"

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

Please forgive my poor knowledge of JS/JScript architecture.

I'm attempting to store the arguments of a [FindChild](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55112/?utm_source=site-search&utm_medium=search-results&utm_campaign=site-search-c&utm_term=find%20child&_ga=1.145055092.139871549.1424808347) call to easily print for debugging. I'm open to other routes to accomplish this, but the current attempt involves a wrapper function, according to [this guide.](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/extending-a-javascript-function/)

```
var FindChildParamsText = ""; 
(function() {
    var copy = FindChild;
    FindChild = function() {    
       FindChildParamsText = copy.arguments;
       return copy.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();
```

I'm having a problem accessing the original method to copy. Is [GetMethods](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/58403/) something I should look into? If so, the overhead would become more than I would like.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: If I understand correctly, this technique is for functions only - those called as `func(...)`. But FindChild is an object method - `obj.FindChild(...)`. You probably can't hook methods in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a wrapper function like this:

```js
function FindChild(Obj, PropNames, PropValues, Depth, Refresh)
{
  // Access PropNames and PropValues as you need
  ...

  var result = Obj.FindChild(Obj, PropNames, PropValues, Depth, Refresh);
  return result;
}
```

and replace all `FindChild` method calls in your tests

```js
obj.FindChild(...);
```

with this custom function:

```js
FindChild(obj, ...);
```